# Docker: Show stopped Docker containers

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker, and I would like to list the stopped containers.

With `docker ps`:

```
sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Nothing appears, because I restarted the machine and I didn't configure them to start the containers automatically.

So when I try to run a container it says:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name=angular_moviemasher  moviemasher/angular-moviemasher
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "/angular_moviemasher" is already in use by container b4428b708711c15233f558e70f58cb7800e23c4a6a57534abfa5818912630a37. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name..
See 'docker run --help'.
```

So I would like to see which Docker containers are already installed and start them.

In the documentation *[Docker Cheat Sheet with examples](https://coderwall.com/p/2es5jw/docker-cheat-sheet-with-examples)* I can only find an example of how to show **running** containers:

> Info of Container
>
> To show running Containers. With -a option, it shows running and
>   stopped Containers.
>
> docker ps

Comment: Not sure why your quote says "running and stopped" and you mention it only shows running, but `docker ps --help` can be your friend here and other places. Note you can also do `docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep Exit | cut -d ' ' -f 1)` to remove all Exited containers -- which will remove the conflicting name error you mention.

Comment: `docker container ls -a`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Like you said `docker ps -a` will show stopped and running containers (all the containers). The following command will only show you the stopped containers.

```
docker ps -a | grep Exit
```

Now you're able to perform `docker logs container-id` on your container to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 14):

Best way to only show stopped containers is to run the following command:

```
docker container ls -f status=exited -a
```

Answer (score 12):

Another option not mentioned in the answers above is:

```
docker container list --all
```

It was added in Docker 1.13 (January 2017), and seems to be [the recommended syntax](https://blog.docker.com/2017/01/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/):

> In Docker 1.13, we regrouped every command to sit under the logical object it’s interacting with. For example list and startof containers are now subcommands of docker container and history is a subcommand of docker image.
>
> `docker container list`
> `docker container start`
> `docker image history`
>
> These changes let us clean up the Docker CLI syntax, improve help text and make Docker simpler to use. **The old command syntax is still supported, but we encourage everybody to adopt the new syntax**.

Answer (score 8):

Well you gave yourself the answer:

> Info of Container
>
> To show running Containers. With **-a** option, it shows running and
>   stopped Containers.
>
> docker ps

So try

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

Comment: No, because it shows all containers, with running containers cluttering the list. It's as if someone asked how to search for file(s) in a directory and you told them to just run the `tree` command and spot it...

Comment: My understanding was that one misunderstood the -a option "In the documentation Docker Cheat Sheet with examples I can only find an example of how to show running containers". "-a" is not about showing only running (which was also emphasized) containers, but to show all of them.

BTW:
Comments like yours are absolutely not helpful for the overall SO community and is one of the reasons why I significantly reduced my time here. It seems many are here just to foster dispute ...

Answer (score 5):

If `docker ps -a` isn't showing anything after a machine restart, try restarting the Docker daemon (happens sometime to me too after a shutdown).

Comment: I dont know how and why but it worked for me! Thanks!